# Where is the Docker source code located (github repo)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to install docker on Angstrom linux, In order to do that I would like to download the source code of docker, and make the files myself.

But I cannot find the source code?

docker.github.io is apparently just the documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://github.com/moby/moby) or [this](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce)?

Comment: Requests to locate an off-site resource are explicitly out-of-scope on StackOverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, the section "some questions are still off-topic", bullet point #4

Comment: what is moby? is it community version of docker?

Comment: “Docker (the company) decided to differentiate Docker (the commercial software products Docker CE and Docker EE) from Docker (the open source project).”

You can see Moby as the open source components composing the product Docker.

Comment: I understand! But about the installing docker using docker, how does one install this on imx6 if it doesnt already have docker?

Comment: You must install Docker on your dev machine, then build Docker using Docker, on your dev machine. After that, you transfer the built binaries to the imx6.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to build [Moby](https://github.com/moby/moby), to make it simple, see Moby as the new name for Docker.

To do so, simply clone the git repository, checkout the tag you want and run a `make` command

```
git clone https://github.com/moby/moby.git
git checkout tags/VERSION
make
```

You will need to have Docker installed on your dev machine to build it.

Comment: *You will need to have Docker installed on your dev machine to build it.* - you need docker to install docker?!

Comment: By default yes, it's actually pretty clever as you wont have to install anything other than Docker on your dev machine, and still be able to build Docker. You can also manually build Docker without using Docker itself but by default, the build process is done inside a container.

Comment: Hi, I dont have docker on my apalis, thats what I need to install, how can I get docker to install docker?

Comment: You can check this https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/
I can give you more insight if you tell me what is your dev machine.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04, and I want to install docker on my apalis imx6 that runs angstrom linux

Comment: I would recommend you to install Docker on your Ubuntu machine following the documentation. And then try to compile Docker for ARM to use it on Angstrom and hope there is no missing dependency for your board.

Comment: I already have docker installed on my PC, how would I compile docker for ARM on my PC? Should I just follow the steps given above and then copy paste the folder on my device?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161184/discussion-between-wassim-dhif-and-meek).

Comment: Addtionally, how can I use the docker command once I copy paste the file on the device? Apologies for the noob questions.

Comment: You can just do a ./docker

Answer (score 11):

The short answer is that Docker Desktop is not entirely open-source, although parts of it are. See [should I be worried?](https://robrich.org/archive/2019/08/17/its-ok-docker-isnt-completely-open-source.aspx)

Docker Desktop includes Docker Engine, Distribution, Docker CLI client, Docker Compose, Docker Content Trust, Kubernetes, and Credential Helper.

As mentioned in https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/README.md

The image distribution engine is on:

https://github.com/distribution/distribution

The source code for Docker Engine is on:

https://github.com/moby/moby

The source code for docker CLI is on:

https://github.com/docker/cli

The source code of docker compose is on:

https://github.com/docker/compose

But to bring these tools to a usable bundle, you need Docker Desktop.

The executable binary distributions of Docker Desktop are on:

https://download.docker.com/